# Will Detox tool scan QR codes

Tags: qr-code, detox

Can someone help me and tell me whether Detox test tool supports QR code scanning for mobile apps (Android & iOS)?
I have seen in the Github page that there was some sort of bug raised and the question has been moved to stackoverflow and I couldn't find it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your application would scan QR codes but here is how you can do to test it.

> ScanQR.jsx

```js
function ScanQR() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  function scan() {
    // here is the logic to scan
    setData(data);
  }
  ...
}
```

Then you will create a mock file `ScanQR.2e2.jsx` following this [instructions](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md)

> ScanQR.2e2.jsx

```js
function ScanQR() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  function scan() {
    // replace the logic to scan with actual data results
    const data = 'some data here';
    setData(data);
  }
  ...
}
```

This way whenever you test you app the mock file will replace the actual file in which you really scan QR codes using camera.

Comment: Thanks Safiy! So if I get this right, it basically kinda 'mocks' the QR code scanning.
I mean it is not going to scan the QR code image as such; it just recognizes a pre-loaded QR image and reads the stand-in data.
Not that I am complaining, I just want to make sure I got the idea/strategy right.
(Needless to say - I am new to Detox! )

Comment: @MishalAlexander Yes, thats exactly the strategy !